# How can main.o not be created last during compilation of C project?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I've watched the installation of GNU make on my computer wth some
attention. It is a relatively simple compilation : it creates successively
an .o file from each .c file, then creates an executable by linking
all the .o files, in the order in which they were created :

```
gcc  -g -O2 -rdynamic  -o make ar.o arscan.o commands.o default.o dir.o expand.o 
file.o function.o getopt.o getopt1.o guile.o implicit.o job.o load.o loadapi.o 
main.o misc.o output.o read.o remake.o rule.o signame.o strcache.o variable.o 
version.o vpath.o hash.o remote-stub.o glob/libglob.a
```

What I don't get here is the following : how can  main.o
not appear last on this list ? Because using the executable on
some arguments is equivalent to calling function main in 
main.c on those arguments, so anything created after main.o
seems useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order in which object files are specified in the gcc command line are irrelevant.  All are linked into an executable, and that executable knows where the `main` function lives.

When all object files are read in, the linker ensures that the `main` function exists along with any functions called directly or indirectly from `main`.

Just because an object file is called `main.o` doesn't necessarily mean that the `main` function lives in that file.

Comment: Strictly speaking the main function is not contained in any object file in this situation, is it ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy What I mean is that while in your case, the `main` function resides in main.o, that doesn't mean a file of that name will always contain `main` in the general case.  There's nothing special about the name of the object file.

Answer (score 0):

The other files contain functions called by `main` directly or indirectly. Without them, `make` can't function.